# friendly_id 5.1.0 using history with finders

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, friendly-id

I'm using the `friendly_id` gem for the first time in a Rails 4.1.6 project, and trying to use `finders`, `history`, and `sluggable` together, but `history` doesn't seem to be working.

I set it up following the railscast tutorial and added `finders` in to my Model's `friendly_id` definition:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :finders, :history]
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
    slug.blank? || title_changed?
end
```

As well as adding in the method from the `friendly_id.rb` initialiser to allow for making a new slug every time the title attribute changes

I've added the slug to the database, migrated, ran `rails g friendly_id` and saved each of the model to create their slug and friendly_id_slug, just not sure why `history` won't work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've figured it out, history needs to be defined before finders in the Model

```
friendly_id :title, use: [:slugged, :history, :finders]
```

Everything's working now :)

Comment: This needs to be added here in BOLD:  https://norman.github.io/friendly_id/FriendlyId/History.html -  Thanks very much for this answer.